# Megasync doesn't start

Tags: 15.04, mega

Yesterday I installed MegaSync with the Nautilus extension and when I restarted the computer (running Ubuntu Desktop 15.04) the MegaSync app doesn't start at all.

I tried running `megasync` in the terminal and nothing, System Monitor does not see MegaSync running. What can I do?

Comment: What does exactly "nothing" mean? No output and goes back to the input line? Or it does not return to the line? Can you also post the output of `ps axu | grep megasync`?

Comment: Nothing means that MegaSync doesn't start, I type in the terminal megasync and the machine automatically gives me back the command line.

Comment: $ ps axu | grep megasync
fer      14427  0.0  0.1   5756  1980 pts/3    S+   15:52   0:00 grep --color=auto megasync
That is what Terminal gives me back.

Comment: Use Pastebin and post the output of `strace megasync`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XgpxWX1k Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Post `ls -l "/home/fer/.local/share/data/Mega Limited/MEGAsync/megasync.lock"`

Comment: fer@fer-S6FM:~$ ls -l "/home/fer/.local/share/data/Mega Limited/MEGAsync/megasync.lock"
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 ago 31 02:21 /home/fer/.local/share/data/Mega Limited/MEGAsync/megasync.lock
fer@fer-S6FM:~$ sudo ls -l "/home/fer/.local/share/data/Mega Limited/MEGAsync/megasync.lock"
[sudo] password for fer: 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 ago 31 02:21 /home/fer/.local/share/data/Mega Limited/MEGAsync/megasync.lock
fer@fer-S6FM:~$

Comment: Why "`sudo`"? Typing random command in your CLI can result in **serious** damage. Avoid typing commands if you don't know what they do and no one tells you so (and clearly you don't know what `ls` does, otherwise you would not have done it with `sudo`). BTW the problem is that that file is owned by `root`. Is not the case that you tried to run Mega with `sudo`, right?...

Comment: Running programs with `sudo`, especially graphical programs, may lead to some major problems like this (wrong ownership of files, that might result in you not being able to log into your system *at all*!). If you really can't avoid messing around with higher privileges on your system, at least use `gksudo` to launch graphical programs.

Comment: Just want to point the origin of your issue: initially you started MEGAsync as a root user (at this point it created directories and files using root as an owner) and then you try to launch MEGAsync as a normal user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is a wrong ownership of some files in the home directory.

Acquire again the property of all the files in that directory via

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER "/home/$USER/.local/share/data/Mega Limited"
```

Where `$USER` is an environment variable with your current username.

Answer (score 7):

The [answer of dadexix86](https://askubuntu.com/a/668272/349837) doesn't work all the time.
At first, I did what he proposed and it worked.

But later on, when the issue reappeared, I found that I had to delete/rename the `megasync.lock` file inside
"`~/.local/share/data/Mega Limited/MEGAsync/`":

Doing that, it worked like a charm.

Comment: This worked for me like a charm on Linux Mint 19. It should be marked as correct answer.

Comment: Make sure there is no related process still running: `pgrep -af mega`. Eventually, kill them with `pkill`/`killall`